# How can I float 4 responsive divs in a container?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a responsive site and having trouble with the floating container. I want it to have four divs directly next to each other with out gaps and without the divs moving onto a new on smaller screens/windows. I've tried a wide range of techniques none of which seem to work. The container should be a maximum of 960px x 460px as each of the divs all have the height of 460px and have a combine width total of 960px.

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried.

Comment: I've tried multiple methods but can't find the right one...
I have four items:
1 - Image 460x85px
2 - Ifram/animation 460x537px
3 - php contact form 460x255px
4 - Image 460x85px

I'm trying to get them all to fit in a rectangle side by side 460x960px so they look like they are a seamless rectangle. I need them to adjust to stay in the rectangle depending on frame size.

Comment: You have several options below that do exactly that. You'd just need to set the max-width on your images/iframes to 100% so that they scale down with the containers.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the `font-size` hack: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/bbek5rq6/

Or use Bootstrap.

The idea to remove spaces is to set `font-size` of those spaces to 0px.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a grid framework to ease the development of responsive layouts:

- http://getbootstrap.com/css/
- http://960.gs/
- http://unsemantic.com/

I am rather fond of the [Jeet](http://jeet.gs/) pre-processor framework which can be used with Stylus or SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using a framework will make your life easier. To answer your question,the simplest solution is to set a max width for the parent, and then use percentages for the children.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="quarter red">
  </div>
  <div class="quarter green">
  </div>
  <div class="quarter blue">
  </div>
  <div class="quarter">
  </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {max-width:960px;}
.quarter {width:25%;height:460px;background:#EEE;float:left;}
.red {background:#990000;}
.green {background:#006600;}
.blue {background:#333366;}
```

You can view this code working here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwdjXo

Updated codepen with placeholder images: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEGNYe

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the super neat flex layout?

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 460px;
  display: flex;
}
.wrap div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div style="background:red"></div>
  <div style="background:blue"></div>
  <div style="background:lime"></div>
  <div style="background:cyan"></div>
</div>
```